# How to Convert XpsDocument to Byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xps

What is the best way to convert [`System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.xpsdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) object to a byte[] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static byte[] GenerateByteArrayFromXpsDocument()
{
    string tempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();

    //GetTempFileName creates a file, the XpsDocument throws an exception if the file already
    //exists, so delete it. Possible race condition if someone else calls GetTempFileName
    File.Delete(tempFileName);

    using (XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(tempFileName, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
         XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDocument);
         writer.Write(/* use my own way to write xps file */);  // use your own way to write write the xps file instead
    }

    return File.ReadAllBytes(tempFileName);
}
```

Comment: this is the accepted answer which solved my problem completely, But it has been downvoted before I edit it and fix it.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert most objects this way, XpsDocument too:

```
BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, anyObject);
    var result=ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This will not work at all, because the XpsDocument does not have the [Serialized] attribute, so an exception will be thrown